# What is the meaning of the starting player rules in Tzolk'in?

Tags: tzolkin

The [rules](http://czechgames.com/files/Tzolkin_EN.pdf) of the board game Tzolk'in state (page 4, bottom left): "Give the Starting Player Marker to the player who most recently sacrificed something.  In case of a tie, give the Starting Player Marker to the player who volunteers for the next sacrifice."

My question: What does this mean?

Probably this is a joke?  (But then, who starts the game?)  Or does this refer to some part of the game which I haven't discovered yet?

Comment: As a general rule, the method for determining the start player in most games is a pointless rule that won't necessarily be obeyed depending on the play group.

Comment: "I should start, but I'm sacrificing my place for this time, which means I shouldn't start, which means I should, which means I shouldn't, ..."

Comment: Tzolk'in disappoints me that the initial resource tiles don't have numbers on them that would force turn order. Also i think going 2nd or 3rd is the best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a joke, referencing the fact that many games these days have means of determining a starting player that are somewhat arbitrarily related to the theme of the game but where there's nothing stopping you from choosing the starting player however you like. For example, the player with the pointiest ears is meant to be the start player for Small World, while Chrononauts has everyone guess the time and the person closest to the truth gets to start.

Comment: In some of my social circles we always say it is the person who has the least experience with the game; as one can imagine this then starts a fight because of who was nominated.

Comment: My general rule is (unless there's a HUGE advantage to going first) have new players go last so they can see what's going on... If everyone's played, winner of previous game goes last (assuming first is advantageous!)

Comment: I've also seen "Most recently visited an island" (Forbidden Island) and "Most recently sequenced insect DNA" (Dinosaur Island).  Oddly enough, we actually had a winner for the DNA sequencing one.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for Germany, but I assume it is or was similar in other countries.
In the <del>good</del> bad old days when gaming was considered something for children, and adults would not play any games (except maybe parents playing with their children), it was natural occurrence that older players were more experienced. Therefore many games from the 70's and 80's had rules like "the oldest player starts" or "the youngest player starts", which gives a hint that the starting player has a little (dis-)advantage.
Practically all other rules defining the starting player - especially nowadays - are humorous paraphrases of "randomly select a starting player", often in a more or less funny way related to the theme of the game. Fearsome Floors for example says that the player should start, who looks most similar to the monster.